# Finding my executable in a Cabal test suite

Tags: haskell, testing, cabal

I'm trying to write a test suite for a cabal project which builds an executable.  I'd like the tests in the suite to run that particular executable, but I don't know where to find it (because my tests might be getting run from a sandbox in some unknown location).

Cabal ought to know where my project's executable is when it calls my test suite.  Is there some way for my test module/program to gather this and other similar information from Cabal, perhaps with the new `detailed-1.0` testing framework?

Comment: Can you not use cabal data-files and the Paths_foo module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a "magic" module you can include in your cabal file to query the paths related to the project.

```
name: myproject

library

  other-modules:       
    Paths_myproject
```

Exported by this module (`import Paths_myproject`) are several `FilePath` values which can be used to query the various paths Cabal uses when installing the project.

```
Paths_myproject.getBinDir        
Paths_myproject.getDataDir       
Paths_myproject.getDataFileName  
Paths_myproject.getLibDir        
Paths_myproject.getLibexecDir    
Paths_myproject.getSysconfDir    
Paths_myproject.version
```