# How to run executables with cabal without any extra output?

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I use `cabal run` to run my programs I always get some extra noise in the output. For example:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-9.4.4 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - output-test-0.1.0.0 (exe:output-test) (first run)
Configuring executable 'output-test' for output-test-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing executable 'output-test' for output-test-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'output-test' for output-test-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( app/Main.hs, /private/tmp/output-test/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-osx/ghc-9.4.4/output-test-0.1.0.0/x/output-test/build/output-test/output-test-tmp/Main.o )
[2 of 2] Linking /private/tmp/output-test/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-osx/ghc-9.4.4/output-test-0.1.0.0/x/output-test/build/output-test/output-test
```

Or at best:

```
Up to date
```

Usually this isn't a big problem, but now I have an executable that generates output that I want to save to a file without this extra text. How can I do that? I can't find a `--quiet` option in the docs.

Comment: calling `cabal install` from your project root should move the generated executable into your path (`~/.cabal/bin` in linux). Then you can run `executable-name <args>`  with no invocation to `cabal`. If `~/.cabal/bin` isn't in your path I think you can run `cabal install -o my_path` or something like (check the docs better) that to move the executable to the folder you want

Comment: Also, does verbosity help?? `cabal run --versbose=0 executable -- <args>`. I haven't tested this

Comment: Maybe even `cabal exec executable -- <args>` can work, since `cabal exec` doesn't run `cabal` itself, but the comand you pass with the enviroment in the cabal project... Sorry for so many comments by the way

Comment: `cabal install --installdir=somepath` works for my use case, but it is not ideal. I don't really want to install anything globally. I've tried `--verbose=0`, but it only adds extra output.

Comment: Possibly related and/or useful: [Finding my executable in a Cabal test suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462593/finding-my-executable-in-a-cabal-test-suite)

Comment: @leftaroundabout I've actually answered a related question myself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73362746/15207568, I guess I could use `cabal list-bin` to find the location of the binary.

Comment: `cabal exec my-executable` works, but only if `cabal build` has been run beforehand. That seems like the best option for me now.

Comment: interestingly `cabal run --verbose=0 my-exec` returns the same output (no extra noise) as `cabal exec my-exe` in my computer. Whereas `cabal run --verbose=1 my-exec` returns `Up to date` followed by the output. I am testing a `hello world` app.

Comment: @lsmor I think you're right. It seems to work on my machine too now. I don't know what I observed before. Edit: Ah, I think I did `cabal run exes --verbose 0`...

Comment: Nice question. I needed that just the other day -- found a way to do it, but can't quite recall the exact flag at the moment.

Comment: (After consulting my own code: I have also solved it with `cabal run --verbose=0`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be that [there was no way](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4652), but these days a simple `-v0` should suffice.

Actually, I've found three defaults for `run` that are unfortunate, in my opinion:

1. `-v0` really ought to be default IMO
2. The target selector really ought to default to `exe:`. (Perhaps it does these days? I haven't kept up with this issue.)
3. Arguments ought to default to going to the executable being run, not to `cabal`.

I have had the following script in my local bin to address these concerns for a while now, feel free to steal it. It adds `exe:` to the target unless there's already a `:` in the executable name, and it adds `--` unless there already is one; these two escape hatches let you change the new default in exceptional circumstances (such as wanting to use `v2-run` with a `test:` selector or because you really do want to pass options to `cabal`).

```
#!/bin/sh

contains() {
    local needle="$1"
    while [ $# -gt 1 ]
    do
        shift
        if [ "$needle" = "$1" ]
        then
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}

executable="$1"
shift
if echo "$executable" | grep -q : >/dev/null
then
    if contains -- "$@"
    then exec cabal v2-run "$executable" -v0 "$@"
    else exec cabal v2-run "$executable" -v0 -- "$@"
    fi
else
    if contains -- "$@"
    then exec cabal v2-run exe:"$executable" -v0 "$@"
    else exec cabal v2-run exe:"$executable" -v0 -- "$@"
    fi
fi
```